# Permission error on auth logout: firebase/ionic/angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I have an ionic3 application using angularfire2 and firebase. I use firbase auth to login to my application, and for retrieving an object from firebase about "currentChallenges". When I use the logout function an error is thrown from Firebase.

**Error message:**

> permission_denied at /currentChallenge: Client doesn't have permission
>   to access the desired data.

I use the following function for my logout, in my auth.service.ts:

```html
logout() {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
    this.firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .signOut().then(() => {
            this.appCtrl.getRootNav().popToRoot(); //root is login page
        });
}
```

I am not sure where/what exactly is causing the error. In my challenges.service.ts is where I make the initial observable object:

```html
private dbCurrentChallengesObservable: FirebaseObjectObservable <any>;
 
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) { 
  this.dbCurrentChallengesObservable = db.object('/currentChallenge');  
}

public getCurrentChallenges(){
  return this.dbCurrentChallengesObservable;
}
```

And then, I use this object in my model (challenges.ts) like this:

```html
ionViewCanEnter(): boolean{
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
}
   
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.currentChallenge = this.challengesService.getCurrentChallenges();
    this.currentChallenge.subscribe(data => {
        if(data.challenge1completed > 0) this.challenge1Completed = true;
        if(data.challenge2completed > 0) this.challenge2Completed = true;
    });
}
```

At first I thought it was related to the subscribe and I added an subscribe().unsubscribe() in an on-ion-leave function in the challenges.ts, but that did not stop the error. But something must still be listening to firebase, which must be stopped upon or even before logout. I just don't know what/where/how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase,//blabla       
this.afDatabase.database.goOffline();//To solve the permission denied 문제.
```

add above statement before signout();

I too took a lot of time on this problem and not a single clue found.
Hope this helps